# mysql - get results at mysql prompt, but not through script?

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

I'm using php to fetch some records from my db and it keeps returning "No results found".  But, when I print the query to the screen and copy and paste it at the mysql prompt, I get 1 row.  Granted, it's a monster query, but shouldn't I get the same results?  What causes that to happen?  Any suggestions on what to check?

Don't know if it's helpful, but here's the query:

```
$q = db_query("SELECT node.nid AS nid, gallery.field_attach_gallery_value AS gallery, 
node.type AS type, node.vid AS vid, ce.field_brochure_link_url AS ce_brochure_url, 
ce.field_brochure_link_title AS ce_brochure_title, 
ce.field_brochure_link_attributes AS ce_brochure_attributes, 
location.field_location_value AS location_field_location_value, 
ce.field_ongoing_value AS ce_field_ongoing_value, 
ce.field_poster_link_url AS ce_poster_url, 
ce.field_poster_link_title AS ce_poster_title, 
ce.field_poster_link_attributes AS ce_poster_attributes, 
ce.field_press_release_link_url AS ce_press_release_url, 
ce.field_press_release_link_title AS ce_press_release_title, 
ce.field_press_release_link_attributes AS ce_press_release_attributes, 
(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ce.field_start_date_value,'%Y-%m-%dT%T'),'%M %d, %Y %h:%i %p')) AS start, 
(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ce.field_start_date_value2,'%Y-%m-%dT%T'),'%M %d, %Y %h:%i %p')) AS end, 
ce.field_web_resources_url AS ce_web_resources_url, 
ce.field_web_resources_title AS ce_web_resources_title, 
ce.field_web_resources_attributes AS ce_web_resources_attributes, 
node_revisions.body AS body, 
node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format, 
node.title AS title 
FROM node node 
LEFT JOIN content_field_attach_gallery gallery ON node.vid = gallery.vid 
LEFT JOIN content_type_exhibitions_and_programs ce ON node.vid = ce.vid 
LEFT JOIN content_field_location location ON node.vid = location.vid 
LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid 
WHERE (node.status <> 0) 
AND (node.type in ('exhibitions_and_programs')) 
AND '2010-01-19' BETWEEN (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ce.field_start_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m-%d')) 
AND (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ce.field_start_date_value2, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m-%d')) 
ORDER BY (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ce.field_start_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), '%Y-%m-%d')) DESC");

$num = FALSE;

while($r = db_fetch_array($q)) {
   $num = TRUE;
   $line = 'ok, found something!';
}

if($num == TRUE) {
  print $line;
} else {
  print 'No records found';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `db_query()` and `db_fetch_array()` are custom functions. You should really `var_dump($q)` and replace your output code at the end entirely with `var_dump(db_fetch_array($q));` to get some debug info on your problem.

Comment: var_dump just gives me: "warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /usr/local/www/s/drupal-6.14/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 160.", which, I already know that it's not working, but, I can't figure out why it works fine if I just run the exact same query at the prompt?

Comment: Pekka's edited answer is correct. You will need to manually escape the `%d` (not %b) in your query, as Drupal is likely trying to interpret those as string arguments.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** You comment that you are using Drupal.

[**From Drupal's docs on db_query**](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query/) (Emphasis mine):

> Runs a basic query in the active database.
>
> User-supplied arguments to the query should be passed in as separate parameters so that they can be properly escaped to avoid SQL injection attacks.
>
> **Valid %-modifiers are: %s, %d, %f, %b (binary data, do not enclose in '')** and %%.
> NOTE: using this syntax will cast NULL and FALSE values to decimal 0, and TRUE values to decimal 1.

So my guess is that Drupal is replacing your `%d`s in your query.

**Old answer:**

`db_query()` is no native PHP/mySQL/mysqli function I know of. Are you using a database wrapper? If so, you need to tell us which one that is, or use the standard `mysql_*` instead.

If all settings are correct, the same result should come up.

What you should check:

- Add a `echo mysql_error();` after the query to see whether it silently fails
- Make sure you are selecting the correct database using `mysql_select_db()`
- Make sure you are using the exact same server and user data for both the phpMyAdmin and the script request.

Comment: I'm using Drupal and this is how I'm doing all of my queries...  So, yes, the db is correct and all of the settings are correct...  All of my other queries work just fine... And, I'm not getting any output from mysql_error()